# Android set last modified time for the file

Tags: android, file, time

I have been using  " public boolean  setLastModified (long time) " for setting the file modified time but it always return false. I have seen few similar posts related to this but none of them could work for me. can someone give me solution for this?

Please do not post me any URL's, I have already seen them :

[file.lastModified() is never what was set with file.setLastModified()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633748/file-lastmodified-is-never-what-was-set-with-file-setlastmodified)

[Is it possible to reset the last modified date of an Android file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169165/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-last-modified-date-of-an-android-file)

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-change-the-file-last-modified-date-in-java/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`setLastModified()` is apparently unreliable on Android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18624), perhaps working on some devices and not on others.

Comment: 7 years later and `touch -m` to android phone sdcard mounted to linux with **SSHFS** and it's still not working *sigh*.

Answer (score 0):

You are told to test the return value, false if it is fail.
Disappointed to find out about that...